# iTunes Connect developer API for own statistics site

Tags: app-store-connect, swift, statistics

I'd like to setup my own statistics site for my own released apps. I'm just wondering, if it's possible to have an iTunes Connect API where I can fetch all statistics from the iTunes Analytics area like downloads, crashes, paid applications, active users, in app purchases, etc.

This kind of question was already asked a couple of years ago (around 2015) but without any appropriate answers.

Just to be clear: I'd like to build my own dashboard and I'm not asking for an export functionality (e.g. xls, csv, etc.) or where I can find some other tools.

Comment: Let’s get this linked to the main question where the answer is “no” Apple doesn’t deliver an API for dashboards or development, but scraping the content might be Possible but against the terms of service.